# Observer Pattern question - JavaScript Object delete itself from a parent array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parent, observer-pattern

I'm trying to write an object relationship that follows an observer pattern where the observer cares about a specific set of events that occur on the subject.

I'm not sure if this is 100% standard, but the way I've constructed it, these event objects are defined within the observer, with custom callbacks that will fire when the event occurs.  When an event occurs on the subject, it goes through all it's observers and looks to see who is watching for this event.  If it finds observers watching for this event, it triggers the observer event's callback.

Since I want my observers to have the flexibility to add and remove, on the fly, events that care to watch, I need for the event object to have the ability to delete itself after running it's callback... say, for instance, if my observer only wants to respond to an event once, then no longer monitor it.

This seems like a good plan, but I know that a JavaScript object can't have call delete() on itself.

I was just curious is anyone else out there had ran into this and had come up with an effective solution.

My only thought was that I could pass the reference to the parent observer object, to it's child event, then when the callback happens, I could call a method within the parent... something like  `removeEvent(this)`  passing the event itself to this function.  The removeEvent function could then splice out the event from it's array of events.  The only complicated problem would be finding the location of this event object in the array.  (taking suggestions on this too, thanks!).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I'd have a go at answering your question but I'm not 100% sure how you've implemented your observer pattern. Perhaps there's something useful in my snippet below. I've assumed that the observation is done via callback functions and I've assumed nothing about the format of that data so I'm using strings.
The crux of my solution is that the callback receives a reference to the Subject (which is usual in the observer pattern). This reference can be used to detach the callback from the Subject.

```
var Subject = {
    observers: {},

    attach: function( eventType, fn ) {
        if( !this.observers[eventType] ) this.observers[eventType] = [];
        this.observers[eventType].push( fn );
    },

    detach: function( fn ) {
        var newObservers,
            eventType,
            i;
        for( eventType in this.observers ) {
            newObservers = [];
            for( i = 0; i < this.observers[eventType].length; i++ ) {
                if( this.observers[eventType][i] !== fn ) newObservers.push( this.observers[eventType][i] );
            }
            this.observers[eventType] = newObservers;
        }
    },

    notify: function( eventType, data ) {
        var i, observers = this.observers[eventType].slice(0);
        for( i = 0; i < observers.length; i++ ) {
            observers[i]( data, this );
        }
    },

    poke: function() {
        this.notify( 'testing', 'I got poked' );
    }

};

var Observer = {

    logEvent: function( data, subject ) {
        console.log( 'Every time: ' + data );
    },

    logEventOnce: function( data, subject ) {
        console.log( 'Just once: ' + data );
        /*
         * THE CRUX
         */
        subject.detach( arguments.callee );
    }
};

Subject.attach( 'testing', Observer.logEvent );
Subject.attach( 'testing', Observer.logEventOnce );

Subject.poke();
//Every time: I got poked
//Just once: I got poked

Subject.poke();
//Every time: I got poked

Subject.poke();
//Every time: I got poked

Subject.poke();
//Every time: I got poked
```

Comment: I like this, but you may want to guard against listeners calling "detach" from within the subject's "notify" loop.  The length of "observers" being changed while in the for/loop is trouble.  Lots of ways to solve this.

Comment: Yes, It's a demo, you'd want to do some bolstering for production. Good point tho :)

Comment: Fixed the notify loop problem as per selbie's comment. We don't want the array we're looping over to be changed during the loop

Answer (score 4):

If you pass in a reference to the event object in your `removeEvent` method, then you can just loop through all of the events and test with the `==` operator -- since the event object you passed in is a reference, it will evaluate to true when compared to the corresponding event object in the loop because they reference the same object in memory.

Comment: thanks for your response Johnathan.  Ok, to pile on complexity, since this is where I'm heading...  If the eventObj is complex with members that are both objects and functions, will "==" suffice?  For instance, `event1 = { var type="click"; var callback=function(){alert('Im event1!')}; };`  `event2 = { var type="click"; var callback=function(){alert('Im event2!')}; };`  Will == be able to tell the difference?

Comment: In that example, event1 and event2 are not equal (==), even though they have the same properties with the same types -- this is because they reference two different locations in memory.  If you did event2 = event1, then JavaScript just makes event2 hold a reference to the same object in memory, it does not create a copy of event1, and thus then they would be equal (==)